# Расширение для Chrome

Tags: css3, google-chrome, javascript, css

Решил попрактиковаться в написании расширения для хрома. И вот встал вопрос, у меня код:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.img.style.border-radius="50px"'
  });
});
```

То есть я, при нажатии на кнопку расширения, хочу изменять свойство border-radius у картинок на странице.
Этот код у меня не работает, в связи с этим и встал вопрос о том, что я делаю не так? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.img.style.border-radius="50px"
```

Что такое `img` и что за метод `border-radius`?

```
(for(var i=0, imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img'); i < imgs.length;i++) {
    imgs[i].style.borderRadius = "50px";
})();
```

Comment: Ну, говорю сразу, я с js не дружу.
Я брал кусок кода из примера, там было
document.body.style.backgroundColor="'red'"
Ну, я думал body это элемент в html коде и backgroundColor его св-во.

Comment: А вот так:
document.getElementById('img').style.borderRadius = '50px'; 
Не прокатит?

Comment: @yet1111 а документацию чуть прочитать никак?) Не прокатит, т.к. метод getElementById ищет в документе тег с айди.

Comment: Обновленный код почему то не работает

Comment: @yet1111 включайте дебаггер и ищите ошибку.

Comment: @lampa замыкание не нужно.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov я так понимаю, что код встраивается в тело документа. Если не замыкание, то две переменные уйдут в глобальную область.

Comment: @lampa, не уйдут:

> Isolated worlds allow each content script to make changes to its JavaScript environment without worrying about conflicting with the page or with other content scripts.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov аа, у них уже всё продумано.

Answer (score 1):

Надо так:

```
code: 'document.img.style.borderRadius="50px"'
```

см. [CSS3 border-radius Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp) JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Уже пробовал.

Comment: img соответственно надо заменить на что-то, так не сработает. у документа нету свойства img.... возможно так:

     document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.borderRadius = "50px"

Comment: Так тоже не получилось :(

Comment: @yet1111 вы что-то делаете не так. все три варианта (суть одна и та же у всех), приведенные здесь, работают. может быть не обновили расширение в списке расширений?

Answer (score 1):

```
code: 'var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
       for (i=0, l=images.length; i<l; i++) {
          images[i].style.borderRadius="5px";
       }'
```

Comment: Странно, но все равно не работает код.

Answer (score 0):

в манифесте:

```
"browser_action": {"default_icon": "icon.png", "default_title": "описание"},
"permissions": ["tabs","activeTab"]
```

в background:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{
code: 'for(var i=0,imgs=document.querySelectorAll("img");i<imgs.length;i++)imgs[i].style.borderRadius="50px";', runAt: 'document_end'
})
})
```

проверенно

Comment: я точно что-то делаю не так

Comment: а конкретнее что не так делали, проверял сразу перед публикацией

Comment: Ну манифест есть, бэкграунд файл есть. Код и там и там как у вас... Загружаю в хром себе и не пашет. (Проверяю на сайте вк)

Comment: какие сообщения в консоле бэкграунда пишет, какие собощения в инспекторе (инструменты разработчика)?

Comment: Ничего не пишет

Comment: так же проверил на вк, все прекрасно работает. попробуйте добавить в permissions: "activeTab"

Comment: пишет Unexpected token ILLEGAL в бэкраунд жс

Comment: смотрите по номеру строки, где ошибка